# Elasticsearch crashed with "fatal error on the network layer"

Tags: elasticsearch, networking, out-of-memory

**Elasticsearch is crashed when several "fatal error on the network layer" Error throwed and end with oom:**

ElasticSearch version: "5.2.2" with single node, and the memory size is 2GB.

Here is the log:

```
 [2017-09-30T17:36:02,095][ERROR][o.e.t.n.Netty4Utils      ] fatal error on the network layer
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.maybeDie(Netty4Utils.java:140)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.exceptionCaught(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.notifyHandlerException(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:851)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341)

[2017-09-30T17:36:02,133][INFO ][o.e.c.s.IndexScopedSettings] [node1] updating [index.refresh_interval] from [-1] to [1s]
[2017-09-30T17:36:02,180][ERROR][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [node1] fatal error in thread [Thread-17], exiting
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*
```

Comment: Does it only happen when you change the refresh interval (`updating [index.refresh_interval] from [-1] to [1s]`) on an index? Also version number, heap size, single node / cluster, current load, anything specific you are doing right before the crash,... — there is so much missing information here

Comment: add more information, actually the refresh interval is changed automatically, i have do nothing to change the configuration, there are another processes write contents to elasticsearch.

Comment: What do you mean with „the refresh interval is changed automatically“? Are you adding ?refresh=1 to your query or what is causing that?

Comment: actually i have not configured the refresh interval, it's default value. I use a bulk api to insert or update the index, and I have not add ?refresh=1 in my query.